# Is this a correct statement: $\sup \omega = \omega + 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm sorry if this is very obvious, but I am re-reading Rudin's Real Analysis, and thinking of $\omega$. Would it be correct to say that the supremum of $\omega$ is $\omega + 1$?  And if so, how can I say $\omega$ is an unbounded set while also saying that it has a least upper bound in the ordinals? What's the best way to say this?

Edit:

$\omega = \{0, 1, 2, \dots \}$

$\omega + 1 = \{0, 1, 2, \dots, \omega \}$

Comment: What do you denote ω?

Comment: Which one of Rudin's books are you talking about? In his *Real and Complex Analysis*, he only mentions the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$.

Comment: $\omega = \{0, 1, 2, \dots \}$

Comment: I'm reading his "Principles of Mathematical Analysis". Forgive me, it is the bootleg edition.  I'm in the first chapter and he is talking about supremums (in the context of real numbers), but I was just thinking about the ordinals.

Comment: Nevermind! Thanks, I realize it is $\sup \omega = \omega$ via Twitter.  Just couldn't compute there but it makes sense now.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you try looking at the subset of the polynomial ring in arbitrary many variables $\Bbb{Z}[\omega,\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots]$ ordered by comparing the largest coefficients first, where $\omega_{j+1} > \omega_j^{m+1} >\omega_j^m$, then the ordinals is the well-ordered set of those with non-negative coefficients. Only the $\omega_j$ can be interpreted as cardinals, not their sums.

Comment: @reuns What polynomial in that scheme corresponds to the ordinal $\omega^\omega$?

Comment: Yes we need to take the well-ordered closure of the indexing of the variables too

Comment: @reuns I understand the ordering, You might have to remind me again what a polynomial ring is, but I might be able to imagine.  What do you mean by the coefficients can be interpreted as cardinals, not their sums?

Comment: For the last part of your question: you have to specify in what a set is (un)bounded (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$ is unbounded in $\mathbb{R}$). What you probably mean to say in this case is that $\omega$ has no maximal element.

Comment: @reuns The problem with your suggestion runs much deeper than that: there _is_ no such simple scheme for thinking about 'all the ordinals', or even 'all the countable ordinals'. It takes a goodly amount of effort even to get past $\epsilon_0$ with any such scheme (e.g., more than Peano Arithmetic can give you!), and there are countable ordinals that you'll never be able to 'name' in such a clean way. (See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_notation )

Comment: Umm... perhaps I missed now deleted comments, but how does that relate the question? @reuns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supremum of a subset $\ S\ $ of an ordered set $\ T\ $ is, by definition, an element $\ t\in T\ $ such that $\ s\le t\ $ for all $\ s\in S\ $ and there does not exist $\ u\in T\ $ such that $\ s\le u < t\ $ for all $\ s\in S\ $.

If $\ S=T=\omega\ $, then there is no $\ t\ $ in $\ t\in T\ $ such that $\ s\le t\ $ for all $\ s\in S\ $, so we can indeed say that $\ \omega = S\ $ is "unbounded" in this case.

If $\ S=\omega\ $ and $\ T\ $ is a set of ordinals with $\ \omega\cup\{\omega,\omega+1\}\subseteq$$ T,$ however, then $\ s\le\omega\ $ for all $\ s\in S\ $, and there is no $\ t\in T\ $ such that $\ s\le t<\omega\ $ for all $\ s\in  S\ $, so $\ \sup S=\sup\omega = \omega\ $ (not $\ \omega+1\ $) in this case.

In fact, if $\ T\ $ is any ordinal, and $\ \alpha\in T\ $, then $\ \sup\alpha=\alpha\ $ if and only if $\ \alpha\ $ is a [limit ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_ordinal). If $\ \alpha=\beta+1\ $ is a [successor ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_ordinal), then $\ \sup\alpha=\beta\ $.

Answer (score 0):

No, $\sup \omega=\omega$; firstly $\omega$ is *an* upperbound for $\omega$:

$$\forall n \in \omega: n \le \omega $$

which is clear as $\alpha < \beta$ iff $\alpha \in \beta$ (iff $\alpha \subsetneq \beta$) for ordinals generally, so $\alpha \le \beta$ iff $\alpha=\beta$ or $\alpha \in \beta$ (or $\alpha \subseteq \beta$ too).

and if the ordinal $\beta$ is an upper bound for $\omega$, so

$$\forall n \in \omega: n \le \beta $$ and note that $\beta \notin \omega$, or otherwise $\beta+1 \in \omega$ and we would have $\beta+1 \le \beta$, contradiction. So $n=\beta$ never holds in the $\le$ clause and

$$\forall n \in \omega: n \in \beta \text{ or: } \omega \subseteq \beta \text{ so } \omega \le \beta$$ making $\omega$ the *smallest* upperbound, hence the sup for $\omega$.